# AttributeError and syntax in Simpy traffic simulation

Tags: python, simulation, traffic, simpy

I am trying to create a discrete event simulation of traffic congestion on a single lane. The lane is divided into 10 segments that are the "width" of each car passing through. These segments all take 1 unit of time to pass. My current set up has cars coming through at the same speed but I will change it to allow for slower moving cars to take longer and create traffic congestion. Each segment of road is a resource that is subject to the request() function if it is currently being used.

I'm doing this with simpy in python. Keep in mind that I have almost no experience with python. Here is my code:

```
import simpy
import numpy

inter_ArrivalTime = 2
car_Speed = 1
c = 1

simpy.seg1 = simpy.Resource(env, 1)
simpy.seg2 = simpy.Resource(env, 1)
simpy.seg3 = simpy.Resource(env, 1)
simpy.seg4 = simpy.Resource(env, 1)
simpy.seg5 = simpy.Resource(env, 1)
simpy.seg6 = simpy.Resource(env, 1)
simpy.seg7 = simpy.Resource(env, 1)
simpy.seg8 = simpy.Resource(env, 1)
simpy.seg9 = simpy.Resource(env, 1)
simpy.seg10 = simpy.Resource(env, 1)

SIM_LOG = []

class Street(object):

    def __init__(self, env, carSpeed):
        self.env = env
        self.carSpeed = carSpeed

    def seg1(self, car):
        yield self.env.timeout(car_Speed)
    def seg2(self, car):
        yield self.env.timeout(car_Speed)
    def seg3(self, car):
        yield self.env.timeout(car_Speed)
    def seg4(self, car):
        yield self.env.timeout(car_Speed)
    def seg5(self, car):
        yield self.env.timeout(car_Speed)
    def seg6(self, car):
        yield self.env.timeout(car_Speed)
    def seg7(self, car):
        yield self.env.timeout(car_Speed)
    def seg8(self, car):
        yield self.env.timeout(car_Speed)
    def seg9(self, car):
        yield self.env.timeout(car_Speed)
    def seg10(self, car):
        yield self.env.timeout(car_Speed)

def car(env, name, Street):
    with Street.seg1.request() as req:
        yield req   
        print("%s enters road at %.2f" % (name, env.now))
        SIM_LOG.append([name, "enters road", env.now])
        yield env.process(Street.seg1(name))
    with Street.seg2.request() as req:
        yield req
        SIM_LOG.append([name, "segment 2", env.now])
        yield env.process(Street.seg2(name))    
    with Street.seg3.request() as req:
        yield req   
        SIM_LOG.append([name, "segment 3", env.now])
        yield env.process(Street.seg3(name))
    with Street.seg4.request() as req:
        yield req   
        SIM_LOG.append([name, "segment 4", env.now])
        yield env.process(Street.seg4(name))
    with Street.seg5.request() as req:
        yield req   
        SIM_LOG.append([name, "segment 5", env.now])
        yield env.process(Street.seg5(name))
    with Street.seg6.request() as req:
        yield req   
        SIM_LOG.append([name, "segment 6", env.now])
        yield env.process(Street.seg6(name))
    with Street.seg7.request() as req:
        yield req   
        SIM_LOG.append([name, "segment 7", env.now])
        yield env.process(Street.seg7(name))
    with Street.seg8.request() as req:
        yield req   
        SIM_LOG.append([name, "segment 8", env.now])
        yield env.process(Street.seg8(name))
    with Street.seg9.request() as req:
        yield req
        SIM_LOG.append([name, "segment 9", env.now])
        yield env.process(Street.seg9(name))
    with Street.seg10.request() as req:
        yield req
        print("%s left the road at %.2f" % (name, env.now))
        SIM_LOG.append([name, "segment 10", env.now])
        yield env.process(Street.seg10(name))

def setup(env, carSpeed, interArrivalTime, c):
    street = Street(env, carSpeed)
    yield env.timeout(interArrivalTime)

    c += 1
    env.process(car(env, c, street))

#random.seed(30)

env = simpy.Environment()
env.process(setup(env, car_Speed, inter_ArrivalTime, c))

env.run(until=60)
```

Running this gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'request'
```

I have 2 questions:
1) What is the cause of this error? Will fixing this cause make my code work?
2) Is there a more optimal way of writing this kind of simulation with simpy? - particularly the segments of road which is a lot of the same code rewritten over and over again.

Comment: A complete stacktrace would have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Street.seg1 is the function seg1 that you defined within the Strett class, not the resource that you defined above (Why do you even that your resource instances in the simpy-Namespace??).
2. Yes, there are better ways.

I think you should toy around with the examples provided in the SimPy docs first and get a little more familiar with both, Python and SimPy, before you continue with your actual simulation.